# select from tag and use as property - vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to get a property from a select tag and use in a property object.
Here is my html:

```html
<div id="app">
    <h3>{{title}}</h3>
    <div class="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Note Title</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" v-model="note.title">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Note text</label>                        
                <textarea class="form-control" v-model="note.text"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Cor</label>                        
                    <select v-model="note.cor">
                            <option disabled value="">Selecione a cor</option>
                            <option value="blue">Azul</option>
                            <option value="green">Verde</option>
                    </select>
                    <span>Cor Selecionada: {{ note.cor }}</span>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addNote">Submit</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-4" v-for="(note, index) in notes">
                <button class="close" @click="removeNote(index)">&times;</button>
                <div class="card-block">
                    <h4 class="card-title" v-bind:style="{ color: note.cor }">{{note.title}}</h4>
                    <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{note.date}}</h6>
                    <p class="card-text">{{note.text}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the Js:

```es6
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        title: 'Notemaster',
        note: {
            title: '',
            text: '',
            cor: ''
        },
        notes: [
            {
                title: 'Visit Hawaii',
                text: 'just kiddind lol',
                date: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
                cor:'blue'
            }
        ]
    },
    methods: {
        addNote() {
            let { text, title } = this.note
            this.notes.push({
                text, 
                title,
                date: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(), 
                cor
            })
        },
        removeNote(index) {
            <!-- apaga o número de itens dispostos no segundo parametro-->
            this.notes.splice(index, 1)
        }
    }
});
```

The value of the select tag works to show at `<span>Cor Selecionada: {{ note.cor }}</span>`;
It works to show the color of the title at `<h4 class="card-title" v-bind:style="{ color: note.cor }">{{note.title}}</h4>`
But I can't create a new note.
The error shown is that `cor` in `this.notes.push({ ... cor })` is not defined.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory, `cor` is not defined in that scope.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```es6
let { text, title, cor } = this.note
                   ^^^
```